Proper use of LINKING VERBS after groups?
How do I use the correct linking verb after a "group". Is there a rule? For example the "team" is, but I can't say the "people" is??? Manchester United is a great soccer team? The Yankees "is" a great baseball team, or The Yankees "are" a great baseball team?

Imho, "linking verb" isn't a useful category when learning English. Use copula instead. But the fact of is being a copula in your context is irrelevant - it's just the same "plurality" issue with Manchester United have / has a lot of dedicated fans.

@FumbleFingers what difference is there between "linking verb" and "copula"?

Owusu-Poku: to illustrate that this question has nothing to do with the class of verb, consider a verb that isn't a linking verb or copula or whatever you want to call it, such as "to face (an opponent)" Manchester Unitedfaces / face the Yankees today in the beach volleyball tournament.

I'm not sure, since by implication I wouldn't use the term "linking verb" anyway. Without specifically googling linking verb vs copula, I'm gonna guess that the highlighted elements in He became angry and He was angry are both linking verbs, but only the second is a copula.

@FumbleFingers then how would you denote the class of verbs that take an adjective as a complement to describe the subject, which both "became" and "was" do here?  What concept would you use to describe the reason for saying "that flower looks pretty" rather than *"that flower looks prettily"?

Middle constructions are typically used to describe general qualities or properties of the subject without implying an active agent, as in "This wine is drinking well" or "The fabric washes well."

...chatgpt says "He looks angry" is also considered a middle construction in English.

In the US and Australia, formal agreement is the norm ('Australia is beating Elbonia in the latest test match'). In the UK, notional (/'logical') agreement is the norm. Thus 'The team are fighting among themselves' / 'The team was founded in 1878.' But some nouns resist or bar notional agreement. 'Behold, the people is one' is found in the KJV (Gen 11:6), but sounds antiquated, and I'd always use plural agreement with this noun of multitude.
